# javascript a simple slide show

Tags: javascript

a simple slide show:  Web document that displays one of the fruit images in approximately the center of the page. Below the image, place three button elements labeled with the names of fruits. (One of them must be the name of the fruit you chose to display.) Pressing a button should change the displayed image to that of the fruit named on the button.

this is what  i got so far

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
   <html>
     <head>
       <style>
         img.displayed {
           display: block;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto 
         }

         #bananas {
           display:none;
         }

         #apples {
           display:none;
         }

       </style>

       <script type="text/javascript">  

         function toggle_visibility(grapes) { 
           var e = document.getElementById(grapes); 
           if(e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
           else e.style.display = 'block'; 
         }

         function toggle_visibility(bananas) { 
           var e = document.getElementById(bananas); 
           if(e.style.display == "block") e.style.display = 'none';
           else e.style.display = 'block'; 
         }

         function toggle_visibility(apples) { 
           var e = document.getElementById(apples); 
           if(e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
           else e.style.display = 'block'; 
         }

    </script>
```

Comment: The way that this is worded, it sounds a bit like you're just giving us a question from an assignment, and want us to do it. I suggest (for your learning) that you make a reasonable attempt to do the task first, and only ask for help here if you run into difficulties while doing so.

Comment: well my issue is I cant get just one image at a time

Comment: Please edit the question and add the specific problem that you are experiencing with your code.

Comment: Are `apples`, `bananas`, and `grapes` the same kind of object? If so, then you're essentially creating the same function over and over since they're signatures are the same. In JavaScript, function myFunc(a) and function myFunc(b) are the same signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions have the same signature since they have the same name. Instead of defining 3 functions for your different images/elements, define one function and reuse it for the id name you're passing to it.

Something like the following:

```
function toggle_visibility(fruit) {
    var e = document.getElementById(fruit);

    if(e.style.display === 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    } 
}
```

Which allows you to do something like:

```
toggle_visibility("banana"); // toggle the element with id 'banana'
```